# From MySQL to Oracle (NOW() and autoincrement ID)

Tags: mysql, oracle, timestamp, auto-increment

I really don't know how to ask this, but... the code will help me:

```
/**
 * Languages table definition
 */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `languages`;
CREATE TABLE `languages`
(
    -- Common:
    `id`      INTEGER    NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT                COMMENT 'Unique registry identifier',
    `created` TIMESTAMP  NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Registry creation TIMESTAMP',
    `updated` TIMESTAMP  NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW() ON UPDATE NOW() COMMENT 'Registry last update TIMESTAMP',
    `active`  BOOLEAN    NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE                  COMMENT 'Virtual deletion flag',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    -- /Common
    `language_id`   INTEGER(2)  UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Language identifier',
    `language_code` VARCHAR(2)           NOT NULL COMMENT 'ISO 639-1 Code',
    `language_name` VARCHAR(20)          NOT NULL COMMENT 'Language name',
    -- Indexes
    UNIQUE KEY `language_id` (`language_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET 'latin1' COLLATE 'latin1_general_ci';

/**
 * Updates multilang field to UTF-8
 */
ALTER TABLE `languages` MODIFY `language_name` VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';

/**
 * Assigns the current TIMESTAMP to the created field without user input
 */
CREATE TRIGGER `insert_languages` BEFORE INSERT ON `languages`
    FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.created = NOW();

/* Insert a record */
INSERT INTO languages(language_id, language_code, language_name) VALUES(10, 'es', 'Español');

/* Update that record (after a few seconds) */
UPDATE languages SET language_name = 'Español (España)' WHERE language_id = 10;
```

When retrieving `* WHERE language_id = 10`, two different timestamps are received without explicitly touching the `TIMESTAMP` fields, also when inserting I don't need to incude an ID. Question is: How do I create the same behavior in Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to use sequences with `BEFORE INSERT` trigger for having autoincrement id
2. You need to maintain the dates using `sysdate` or `systimestamp` or `localdate` ... instead of `NOW()` also in triggers, `BEFORE INSERT` and `BEFORE UPDATE`

Comment: Here's an auto increment sequence / trigger example - http://jen.fluxcapacitor.net/geek/autoincr.html

Comment: @Phil thanks a lot, that helped me a lot. zerkms I gues I need to include all in a single trigger, right? I mean dates and sequences.

Comment: @Edgar: as you wish. Both solutions (1 or several triggers) will work the same

Comment: @zerkms thanks I was under the wrong impression than "the most triggers, the most slow".

Comment: MySql 5.2: NOW() works for me inside a trigger, given that I dont use BEGIN... END.